# Separate rows with special values

Tags: bash, awk

I have two text files.

My first text file looks like this:

```
2 3
5 9
```

The second text file looks like this:

```
4 2 3
3 6 2
1 5 9
```

I'm trying to separate lines where the values of columns 2 and 3 in the second file have the same values as those in columns 1 and 2 of the first text file.

I'm trying this script but I'm currently not successful and the output is empty.

```
set a=`awk '{print $1}' 1.txt` 
set b=`awk '{print $2}' 2.txt`
set cc=1
foreach ii ($a)
awk '($2==$a[$cc] && $3==$b[$cc]) {print$0}' 2.txt >> output.txt
@ cc++
end
```

---

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: row 1 and 3 of second file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep -f`:

```
grep -f 1.txt 2.txt
4 2 3
1 5 9
```

**Edit:** If you want to match only `$2` and `$3` in `2.txt` then use this `awk` command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} a[$2]==$3' 1.txt 2.txt
4 2 3
1 5 9
```

Comment: @user3891747 why are you switching between the answers?

Comment: @AvinashRaj It's the OP's right to choose the answer that works for him.

Comment: yes, you are correct. At first he selected anubhava's then your's now again he selected anubhava's.

Comment: This will only co-incidentally produce the expected output from THAT SPECIFIC posted sample input, though, it doesn't provide a solution to the stated problem of matching the values from 1.txt against **fields 2 and 3** of 2.txt. Try it if the sample input 2.txt contained a line like `2 3 1` or `1 52 35` or ....

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ sub(/\r/, ""); } NR == FNR { a[$1 FS $2]++; next } $2 FS $3 in a' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
4 2 3
1 5 9
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to remove `\r`s? +1 anyway for the right approach and I'm deleting my answer as it's almost identical.

Comment: @EdMorton Text editor shows CRLF when I copied it. Just want to make sure it works whatever the format is.

Comment: OK. FWIW I don't see that when I copy/paste. Maybe mention it as an option? By the way, You don't need the `++` on the array population and Im surprised you don't need parens around `$2 FS $3`.